# How to use Stemming algorithm for a list of words in python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a word list:

```
'AWS', 
'jQuery', 
'jQuery', 
'Sliding', 
'jQuery', 
'jQuery', 
'Manipulating', 
'Us!'
```

I removed common words and need to apply stemming to make the word list more clear.

My Code to remove common words:

```
raw2 = second_headers CORPUS = Common_word_corpus  #my personal word corpus added here

corpus = [w.lower() for w in CORPUS]  
processed_H2_tag = [w for w in raw2.split(' ') if w.lower() not in corpus] 

print(processed_H2_tag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
# download wordnet
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')

# import these modules
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
nltk.download('wordnet')

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

# choose some words to be stemmed
words = ['AWS', 
'jQuery', 
'jQuery', 
'Sliding', 
'jQuery', 
'jQuery', 
'Manipulating', 
'Manipulateing', 
'Manipulate', 
'Us!']
 
for w in words:
    print(w, " : ", lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB))
```

Output:

```
AWS  :  aws
jQuery  :  jquery
jQuery  :  jquery
Sliding  :  slide
jQuery  :  jquery
jQuery  :  jquery
Manipulating  :  manipulate
Manipulateing  :  manipulate
Manipulate  :  manipulate
Us!  :  us!
```

Comment: Im getting an output like this.. but words such as Manipulateing should be stemmed as manipulate. AWS  :  aw
jQuery  :  jqueri
jQuery  :  jqueri
Sliding  :  slide
jQuery  :  jqueri
jQuery  :  jqueri
Manipulating  :  manipul
Us!  :  us!

Comment: The implementation of a (porter) stemming algorithm gives you no finegrained control how the stem is generated. A stem can actually be **different** from the true linguistic base form. Do you look for a lemmatization approach instead?

Comment: yes, lemmatization approach will be appropriate if so to get a clean output. How can it be done.

Comment: I updated the answer as requested in your comment.

Comment: getting a error as   NameError                        
<ipython-input-16-f67d9d8aff5f> in <module>
      2 from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
      3 from nltk.corpus import wordnet
----> 4 nltk.download('wordnet')
      5 
      6 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined

Comment: My bad. Forgot the `import nltk`. Will update.

Comment: It works just as needed. Thank you for the solution